# Formato 001-000001 en una caja de texto (editbox)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms

Quiero ingresar datos a una caja de texto la app es windows forms, lo que quiero ingresar es en este formato `001-000001` los dos primeros digitos son cero el tercer digito del `1` al `9` el cuarto digito un `-` del quinto digito al decimo de `0` a `9`, como podría hacerlo?

```
private void txtGuiaRemision_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        string valor = txtGuiaRemision.Text;
        string re1 = "(\\d+)";
        string re2 = "([-+]\\d+)";

        Regex r = new Regex(re1 + re2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        Match m = r.Match(valor);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            String int1 = m.Groups[1].ToString();
            String signed_int1 = m.Groups[2].ToString();
        }
    }
```

No logro hacer lo que deseo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seria mas simple si usas el control [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)  podrias definir el `Mask` del control con este formato que mencionas

[MaskedTextBox in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/maskedtextbox-in-C-Sharp/)

Ademas si aplicas una expresion regular no la deberias implementar en el keypress, sino que lo harias en el Validating, la expresion regular aplica cuando quieres salir del textbox, o sea cuando se ingreso todo el contenido

[How to: Display Error Icons for Form Validation with the Windows Forms ErrorProvider Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xht7x2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hola Leandro, lo haré con el control que me recomiendas y te aviso.

Comment: Leandro con el MaskedTextBox ya no necesito el errorProvider? o lo recomendabas si es que usaba regex?

Comment: claro con el MaskedTextBox no necesita el erroprovider porque no hay ningun error que mostrar, solo aplica la mascara. Si usas el Validating con al regex entonces si esta no machea el mensaje lo muestras mediante el error provider

Comment: ...Aunque podría mostrar el icono mientras no haya completado el campo, incluso con un MaskedTextBox (a eso me refería)

Comment: si es verdad, en realidad habia apuntado a la validacion de al regex, si quiere validar algo adicional seguro se tendra que usar la misma tecnica del Validating y errorprovider

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a la respuesta de [@Leandro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/17848/127), si quisieras usar regex para validar ese formato, sería:

```
^00[1-9]-[0-9]{6}$
```

- `^` coincide con el inicio del texto
- `00` con el literal `"00"`
- `[1-9]` con 1 dígito que no sea `"0"`
- `-` con 1 guión
- `[0-9]{6}` con 1 dígito, repetido 6 veces
- `$` con el fin del texto

#### Código

```cs
string valor = "001-000001";
Regex re = new Regex(@"^00[1-9]-[0-9]{6}$");

if (re.IsMatch(valor)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Válido");
} 
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
```

<kbd>[demo en ideone.com](http://ideone.com/mIOTLI)</kbd>

Comment: Gracias @Mariano